# How to create embed messages from bots?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I'm quite new with discord bots, and I'd love if someone could tell me how I can make "embed" messages, heres an example:[image: embedded image]

Here's the code I use:

```
@client.event async def on_message(message):
    if message.content == "=displayembed":
        embed = discord.Embed(
            title = "Title",
            description = "This is a description",
            colour = discord.Colour.blue()
        )

        embed.set_footer(text="This is a footer.")
        embed.set_image(url="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/520265639680671747/533389224913797122/rtgang.jpeg")
        embed.set_thumbnail(url="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/520265639680671747/533389224913797122/rtgang.jpeg")
        embed.set_author(name="Author Name", icon_url="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/520265639680671747/533389224913797122/rtgang.jpeg")
        embed.add_field(name="Field Name", value="Field Value", inline=False)
        embed.add_field(name="Field Name", value="Field Value", inline=True)
        embed.add_field(name="Field Name", value="Field Value", inline=True)

        await client.say(embed=embed)
```

Comment: I am confused. You show code (that looks okish) - you show a picture of a embedded message ... but ... what is wrong with any of both?

Answer (score 2):

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content == "=displayembed":
        embed = discord.Embed(
            title = "Title",
            description = "This is a description",
            colour = discord.Colour.blue()
        )

        embed.set_footer(text="This is a footer.")
        embed.set_image(url="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/520265639680671747/533389224913797122/rtgang.jpeg")
        embed.set_thumbnail(url="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/520265639680671747/533389224913797122/rtgang.jpeg")
        embed.set_author(name="Author Name", icon_url="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/520265639680671747/533389224913797122/rtgang.jpeg")
        embed.add_field(name="Field Name", value="Field Value", inline=False)
        embed.add_field(name="Field Name", value="Field Value", inline=True)
        embed.add_field(name="Field Name", value="Field Value", inline=True)

        await client.send_message(message.channel, embed=embed)`
```

Comment: You should just replace client.say with bot.send_message(message.channel, embed=embed) because client.say can only be used in a command decorator

Comment: client.send_message*